# Underline full width of paragraph (even if text doesn't extend all the way)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create the look of a recipe card online:

[image]

As such, I am trying to have the underline go the full width of the paragraph, even if the text does not. Right now, I am trying to use text-decoration: underline, but it only extends as long as the text:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline;
    width: 200px;
}
div {
    width: 400px;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/FYNAM/1/

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well I don't know much about HTML. But I do know there is a tag called <hr> that does what you are asking... as for coloring it you will probably need to look and see if it has CSS styling enabled.

Comment: <hr> Would give a big space in between the <p>. But CSS could fix that. @AlbertRenshaw

Comment: Quick google search returned that apparently setting the `background-color:` style property of the <hr> tag changes the HR color.

Comment: @Shrink You're right! I think line-height or something fixes it (again I know VERY little html and css)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw thanks for the suggestion, but I would have to put an <hr> tag between each line, and I'm trying to avoid splitting the paragraph into individual lines.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian wouldn't I need to separate each line into a separate tr? I'm wondering if there is a solution that would avoid this

Comment: You could use a pseudo element for the last line.

Comment: kind of ugly, but if you know the line-height you could use a background image (possibly inlined data uri) with the appropriate height and repeat-y

Comment: how about `text-align:justify;` on div? This would spread text to full width and so the underline.

Comment: @gp.Yes, that's the most usable solute I've seen. I was just wondering if it could be done with ragged-edges

Comment: Solution using a pseudo element - http://jsfiddle.net/jcWc2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.rtv {
  position: relative;
}

.abs {
  position: absolute;
}

.full-underline {
  width: 100%;
}

.full-underline span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border-bottom: 0.8px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content tl m20 rtv">
  <div class="full-underline abs">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>

  <h3>NAMA PEKERJAAN :</h3>
  <h1>PEKERJAAN EMERGENCY PEMBERSIHAN BENDA ASING DI TOWER 07 SECTION NGENA-TUBAN</h1>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNjLS.png)

You can adjust the span height with the size of the text

Comment: Yup, this does it, thanks! In the code-snippet, the text wasn't lining up for me properly (line-height was less than the height of the text in the <h3>), but with a little fiddling it worked great: https://jsfiddle.net/n8ej526w/

Answer (score 2):

Stupid solution, but if your line height is the same across all <p> (no nested elements with different line-height) you can use background image.

Comment: You don't have to use images for background-images.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by modifying what happens after your p tag as follows

```
p:after {
    content:  " ______________________________________________";
}
```

This was a quick down and dirty solution, but I think you'll be smart enough to take it from here ;)

Good luck.. and great question! You had my vote

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FYNAM/4/)

Answer (score 0):

add following to your css:

```
div { display: block; width: 100%; }
div > p { display: block; width: 100%; }
```

or, you could also try:

```
div { width: 100%; }
div > p { display: block; }
*remove width from 'p'
```

It should solve your issue.